# How do I transfer my Solana token from Mainnet to Devnet?

Tags: solana

I created my Solana token on Ubuntu. I now want to send my newly created token and some remaining SOL to my Phantom wallet Devnet. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can’t. Tokens only exist on the chain you crest them on. If you made them mainnet they can’t be moved to devnet.

On devnet you can run

solana airdrop 1

From the solana cli to get sol and

spl-token transfer (amount) (token) (address)

To send from the cli

Answer (score 0):

To build on gbachik's answer, Solana Devnet and Solana Mainnet are two *entirely separate* chains. They both have the name "Solana" in them, but besides that, they are NOT connected.

They are two separate chains with different purposes.

Therefore, you can't transfer Devnet tokens to Mainnet, just like you can't transfer ETH from Ethereum to Solana.

(You can't literally transfer ETH from Ethereum to Solana, but you can practically with Wormhole/bridging. But no one is going to build a Wormhole/bridge from Devnet to Mainnet because they'd lose all of their money, as the value of SOL on Devnet is $0.)